# Azure Virtual Network / VM's Setup to Share One Public IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I've recently setup a point to site VPN on Azure. In doing so I have created:

1. Azure Virtual Network
2. Azure Virtual Network Gateway
3. Azure Virtual Network Gateway IP (static)
4. Azure VM

I was under the impression that any VM set to use the above said Virtual Network would all share the same public IP? However it appears that the Azure VM i setup is instead using its own dynamic public IP.

Is there a way to route any VM on the Custom Virtual Network I created through one public IP? IF so - how can I do this?

*According to your description, you have create a point-to-side VPN. in this scenario, we can remove the public IP addresses from VMs, then you can access your VMs with private IP addresses via VPN.*

You are correct - I have the VPN working correctly. My only concern is this, it'd be great that if any of those VM's in that private network shared the same static IP - that way I could grant access to that IP in my firewall to other systems i have in other hosting platforms (as they are all typically locked down by ip).

It sounds like your reference to availablity sets may be the phrase i was looking for to further google.. i will check it out and let me know

please let me know if anything I added above changes your answer/recommendations :)

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that any VM set to use the above said
>   Virtual Network would all share the same public IP?

You are talking about Azure ASM module (classic). In ASM module, VMs can use the same public IP address(NAT).

> However it appears that the Azure VM i setup is instead using its own
>   dynamic public IP.

In Azure resource module, we can create Azure VMs with different Public IP addresses.

> Is there a way to route any VM on the Custom Virtual Network I created
>   through one public IP?

According to your description, you have create a point-to-side VPN. in this scenario, we can remove the public IP addresses from VMs, then you can access your VMs with private IP addresses via VPN.

If you want to access those VMs from Internet and use one public IP address, we can create VMs in the same availability set, and deploy a **Internet facing load balancer**, then add NAT rules to them, in this way, we can access those VMs use the same public IP address and different ports.

Comment: Thanks - looking into availability sets - i also updated my question based upon your feedback

Comment: @99823 If your P2S VPN run correctly, we can via VPN to access them with private IP address, like 10.0.0.4/24. if you want those VMs can be accessed via the internet, we can deploy VMs in the same availability sets, and create a Load balancer for them, in this way, we can access them via the load balancer public IP address, also you can add this public IP address to your firewall (on-prem), in this way, we can access those VMs with the same public IP address or access them via VPN with private IP address.

Comment: @99823 Also if you want to access those VMs via VPN and use the same private IP, we can deploy a internal load balancer, so we can access VMs with the private IP address and different ports.  Please let me know if you would like further assistance.